# NSString make certain words lowercase

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have users check certain phrases for it to build an email. The phrases are separated by a comma but I need the phrases to be lowercase unless it starts with an I or I'm. It works great unless the phrase starts "It"  The phrase remains uppercase. I need it to be lowercase.

CODE

```
    NSString string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, ",boxesChecked[idx]];
    // strings are in an array
    [boxesChecked enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    if (idx == 0) { //first string

        if ([string rangeOfString:@"I'm"].location != NSNotFound) {
            // leave uppercase
        } else if ([string rangeOfString:@"It"].location != NSNotFound) {
            string = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:[[string substringToIndex:1] lowercaseString]];

        } else if ([string hasPrefix:@"I"]) {
            // do nothing

        } else {
            string = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:[[string substringToIndex:1] lowercaseString]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the phrases are separated by comma, and you only want to examine the start of the phrase, I'd use componentsSeparatedByString to break out the individual phrases and just examine the starting chars vs rangeOfString.  (But why it's failing as you describe is not clear on first glance.)  (Though do note that you will lower-case a non-leading stand-alone "I".)

Comment: That's what I am trying to avoid. I think it sees the I in It and leaves it uppercase

Comment: Lower case everything. the using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range: and up case all the words that are 'i' and i'm .... done and done

Comment: @John - although make sure that "i" is followed by whitespace.

Comment: Jeff, if you scan for "I " vs "I" then you will not erroneously pick up "It".  (And it seems to me that you should probably be scanning for "IT" rather than "It".)

Comment: (Any reason you don't keep "I'll" or "I'd" upper-case?)

Comment: hmmm, didn't think of those!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the string to lowe case with this command

NSString *myString = @"Hello, World!";
NSString *lower = [myString **lowercaseString**]; // this will be "hello, world!"